# Which browser contains "com.google.GooglePlus" in the agent string?

Tags: user-agent, iphone, google-plus, ipad

I noticed the following agent user strings hitting my website and wondered which browser is this user string for?

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad2; iPad; U; CPU OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; en_GB) com.google.GooglePlus/10352 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/K93AP (gzip)
```

and

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhoneUnknown; iPhone; U; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X; en_GB) com.google.GooglePlus/8654 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/N42AP (gzip)
```

Could it be the Google Plus app on the iPad/iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are from the Google+ app running on the iPad and iPhone. It's running a modified Chrome browser.

The mention of Mozilla/5.0 has to do with the history of User Agent Strings, and nothing to do with who built the software. See more here: http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/